# WITH cte UPDATE SET <multiple> fails, individual UPDATE SET works

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, common-table-expression

Sorry it's a longer one.  I made it code complete.

The real code involves buckets of data for a detailed report.  My cte block fails.  The alternative is to write a number of UPDATE blocks of one SET and a join in each -- ugly but works.

In the given cte block, I can only get Hair to populate, no matter where I put it in the cte block.  In the UPDATE block lower down, everything works perfectly.  (In my real-world situation, my cte join has about 140k records and the update returns a random number of records each time :/ )

What stupid mistake am I making this time?

Thanks,
Thys

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempList') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempList
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempValues') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempValues

CREATE TABLE #TempList (
    Name NVARCHAR(20),
    Hair NVARCHAR(20),
    Height NVARCHAR(20),
    Job NVARCHAR(20)
)
CREATE TABLE #TempValues (
    Name NVARCHAR(20),
    VariableName NVARCHAR(20) ,
    VariableValue NVARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO #TempList
        ( Name ,
          Hair ,
          Height,
          Job
        )
VALUES
    ('Fred', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('Wilma', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('Barney', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('Betty', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('Pebbles', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('Bammbamm', NULL, NULL, NULL)

INSERT INTO #TempValues
        ( Name ,
          VariableName ,
          VariableValue
        )
VALUES
    ('Fred', 'Hair','Dark'),
    ('Fred', 'Height','6-1'),
    ('Fred', 'Weight','220'),
    ('Wilma', 'Hair','Red'),
    ('Wilma', 'Height','5-5'),
    ('Wilma', 'Weight','125'),
    ('Barney', 'Hair','Blond'),
    ('Barney', 'Weight','195'),
    ('Barney', 'Job','Worker'),
    ('Barney', 'Married','Yes'),
    ('Betty', 'Hair','Dark'),
    ('Betty', 'Height','5-3'),
    ('Pebbles', 'Hair','Red')

;WITH cte_name AS (
     SELECT TL.Name ,
            TL.Hair ,
            TL.Height ,
            TL.Job ,
            TV.VariableName ,
            TV.VariableValue
        FROM #TempList TL
            JOIN #TempValues TV ON TV.Name = TL.Name
     )
UPDATE cte_name 
    SET 
        cte_name.Height = 
            CASE  cte_name.VariableName
                WHEN 'Height' THEN cte_name.VariableValue
            END ,   
        cte_name.Hair = 
            CASE  cte_name.VariableName
                WHEN 'Hair' THEN cte_name.VariableValue
            END ,
        cte_name.Job = 
            CASE  cte_name.VariableName
                WHEN 'Job' THEN cte_name.VariableValue
            END

SELECT * FROM #TempList
SELECT * FROM #TempValues

--UPDATE #TempList SET Hair = NULL , Height = NULL , Job = NULL

-- Run either the top UPDATE or these updates
UPDATE #TempList
    SET Height = TV.VariableValue
        FROM #TempList TL
            JOIN #TempValues TV ON TV.Name = TL.Name
        WHERE TV.VariableName = 'Height'
UPDATE #TempList
    SET Hair = TV.VariableValue
        FROM #TempList TL
            JOIN #TempValues TV ON TV.Name = TL.Name
        WHERE TV.VariableName = 'Hair'
UPDATE #TempList
    SET Job = TV.VariableValue
        FROM #TempList TL
            JOIN #TempValues TV ON TV.Name = TL.Name
        WHERE TV.VariableName = 'Job'
```

Comment: you need to update the underlying table #TempList and not the running cte_name.

Comment: Agreed with @andrews. Also, your proper script may be different, but your CTE isn't even needed here. You can accomplish the exact same thing with a regular UPDATE from a JOIN

Comment: I have tried modifying your original CTE but it did't work. I have also tried to use MERGE which didn't work for me either. So in the end I have come up with the update version using PIVOT. See my answer below. Do you need update Weight column too?

Comment: Yup I know this can be accomplished in other ways.  I have a complex problem and this is a (big) simplification.  The CTE updates #TempList automatically -- that's the way it works.  What beats me is: a) why does this not work and b) why does only hair populate?

Comment: @ThysCoetzee I didn't notice your last comment yesterday. Did you have chance to test my version of the cte? Is the performance acceptable?

Comment: @Andrews Sorry for my delay in responding -- was wrestling the beast!  Yes, the performance of your code was good.  Still fail to see what the error was in my original code though.  Luckily for us all there is usually more than one way to skin the SQL cat!

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Wouldn't you mind accepting my answer if it worked ;)?

Comment: Done :-) it was most helpful in my progress.  Any idea what was actually wrong with my code?

Comment: Actually, the very first version of my CTE without pivot behaved similarly to yours: it would update only hair col, though the results were deterministic, not running like in your case, because I changed it to update the underlying table instead of CTE. But I'm still curious to find out why my CTE version without pivot didn't work. Unfortunately, I'm short of time now (feature release deadline) but when I find some more time I will try to find out why my initial CTE version didn't work. I will add it's code to my answer.

Comment: I've added the non-working UPDATE version just for reference. See the updated answer. I'm also curious why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make it work, completely replace your existing cte with the one below:

```
;
with cte as (            
    select Name,[Hair],[Height],[Job] from #TempValues tv
    pivot (min(VariableValue) for VariableName in ([Hair],[Height],[Job]) ) pvt
) 
UPDATE t
SET    
        t.Height = ISNULL(cte.Height, t.Height),            
        t.Hair = ISNULL(cte.Hair, t.Hair),
        t.Job = ISNULL(cte.Job, t.Job)            
from #TempList t
join cte on cte.Name = t.Name
```

Having run the above query over your data, `select * from #TempValues` produces the following output (I have also added `ID int not null identity(1,1)` to the `#TempList` table):

[image]

Explanation:

At first we convert vertical properties/values into horizontal columns using [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx), so `select * from cte` produces the following results:

[image]

we then filter out NULL values in the UPDATE call with ISNULL(...) .

If you need the Weight column too, just add it after `[Job]` in `pivot(...)` clause and in the UPDATE section.

Hope this helps.

**PS.** 2/15/2017 Adding this non-working UPDATE version for reference:

```
UPDATE t
SET    
    t.Height = 
        CASE  tv.VariableName
            WHEN 'Height' THEN tv.VariableValue
        END ,   
    t.Hair = 
        CASE  tv.VariableName
            WHEN 'Hair' THEN tv.VariableValue
        END ,
    t.Job = 
        CASE  tv.VariableName
            WHEN 'Job' THEN tv.VariableValue
        END
FROM #TempList t
JOIN #TempValues TV ON TV.Name = t.Name
```

Note, this is a direct `UPDATE` without CTE, if I remove `#TempValues` JOIN and add the JOIN to CTE, the result is the same: it updates only the first property for each Name. If you switch Hair and Height in the `INSERT ... VALUES (...)` list for each Name, then Height will be updated instead of Hair.

I'm yet to find out why it behaves like that. Will post here if I find something.

Comment: Thanks @Andrews.  You explain things clearly -- appreciate that for sure.  In my RL problem I just run a series of updates, with the obvious hit on performance.  The CTE was supposed to reduce the number of UPDATE calls.  I'll see if PIVOT improves things here.  Thankfully there is usually more than one way to skin a coding cat, but as to why the CTE behaves so poorly...

Comment: @ThysCoetzee thanks for the feedback, let me know if the performance of my cte is acceptable for you.

Comment: curious hmm.  At least you get the first one to update, irrespective of what is first.